# Product of a Normal Distribution and Chi-Square Distribution?

Tags: probability

I am reading this paper over here https://www.jstor.org/stable/2984123 where the following statement is made (page 3):

*The joint sampling distribution of $s_i$ and $x_i$ may be written, apart from the constant of integration:*

$$\frac{s_i^{n-1}}{\sigma_i^n \sqrt{\sigma^2 + \sigma_i^2}} \exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{n s_i^2}{\sigma_i^2} + \frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{\sigma^2 + \sigma_i^2}\right)\right) dx_i ds_i
$$

$$L = -n \sum \log(\sigma_i) - \frac{1}{2} \sum \log(\sigma^2 + \sigma_i^2) - \frac{1}{2} \sum \left( \frac{n s_i^2}{\sigma_i^2} + \frac{(x_i - \mu)^2}{\sigma^2 + \sigma_i^2} \right)
$$

**My Question:** I am trying to understand how this formula was derived.

Doing some further reading, I think that the above result comes from Cochran's Theorem (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cochran%27s_theorem) - that is, the sampling mean and the sampling variance are independent from one another.

Furthermore, I know that that the distribution of the sample variance follows a Chi-Square Distribution and the distribution of the sample mean follows a Normal Distribution. Thus, I think that the above equation might be a multiplication of a Chi-Square Distribution and a Normal Distribution.

**However, I am having trouble taking this information together to write the above equation**

Conceptually, I know that the product of a Normal Distribution and a Chi-Square Distribution should look something like this:

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}\sigma} \exp\left(-\frac{(x-\mu)^2}{2\sigma^2}\right) \times \frac{1}{2^{k/2}\Gamma(k/2)} x^{k/2-1} e^{-x/2}$$

**But I don't know how to re-arrange the terms to get something similar to the desired equation.
Can someone please show me how to do this?**

Thanks!

**References:**

- [What is the joint distribution of sample mean and sample variance of normal distribution?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1000227/what-is-the-joint-distribution-of-sample-mean-and-sample-variance-of-normal-dist)

Comment: Transform chi square random variable $x= s_i^2/\sigma_i^2$